# How to figure out which APP downloaded a file OR requested a download?

Tags: applications, permissions, 7.0-nougat

I found that a file (which was an apk for a new App) was downloaded several times without asking for a permission. My phone is Samsung Galaxy 7 with Android V 7.0. How can I find which App did the download?

Comment: probably malwares

Comment: Yeah I guess so! but I want to figure which App contains malware.

Comment: Hard to tell. Try browsing the app list may be you'll notice apps with weird names

Comment: As it seems nobody wants to answer this, a possible but cumbersome approach: Assuming that download would be repeated, and further assuming you know how fast that will happen (and the interval isn't too big), you could install a [Firewall app](//android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377) (yes, there are some working even without root) and block as many apps as you dare. If the interval passes w/o the download, set one app free, then another – until the download happens again. The last app set free then is the most likely candidate.

Comment: If that's acceptable as answer for you, just let me know and I'll "convert" it. But you might wish to try it first. One thing I'm not sure of: what if an app orders the download manager to deal with that? If you restrict that app, would the download still happen? Or should you try a [Permission Checker](://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379) first to check apps for `ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER`/`ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED`/[`DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION`](//android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION)?

Comment: Honestly, I deleted some suspicious apps one day after I asked this question and the download stopped. I couldn't afford more downloads!! But I was curious to know if I could track the downloader app. Anyway​ your solution seems reasonable. just post it!

Comment: you have the size and you have the last modified date of the downloaded file. and the name. you probably should create a `Receiver` and in that check for those items. and alert yourself if any of those things are suspicious .